# How to crop off top of display

Tags: raspbian, python, chromium

So I'm working on a Spotify jukebox that displays album art.  I have a Python script that opens the URL hosting the art in chromium, and updates it when the song changes, by opening a new tab.  My problem is that, in kiosk mode, when the script launches the updated URL for the latest song's art, nothing happens.  I believe this has something to do with the nature of kiosk mode.  What does work is opening the URL *not* on in kiosk mode.  When I do this, the script simply opens a new tab.  The problem with this is that you see the search and menu bars, which ruins the jukebox look.  Would it make sense to somehow crop off the top of the display in settings? If so, how would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that, even if you opened a new tab each time and it gave the effect you were looking for, sooner or later you'd have hundreds of tabs open and run out of memory.

Would it perhaps be better to point the browser at a page which automatically refreshes itself every few seconds?

If you point the browser at some HTML which embeds the image and refreshes itself, I think that should give the result you want.

Untested HTML which should show the image and refresh every 10 seconds:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
<body>
<img href="http://path.to.your/image.jpg">
</body>
```

All that said, IMHO using a browser to display a picture is a huge overkill, like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.  There are many image viewers and ways to display images, and if all you want to do is display an image from a Python script, I'd do it directly in the Python.